# Shell logout after exec redirection for stdin

Tags: bash, shell, exec

As described in advanced bash script-guide, exec can be used to redirect I/O.
So I just write some cases in my shell. Redirecting stdout or stderr works well, but redirecting stdin makes the shell logout. Any explanation?

Commands:

```
exec < file
```

Comment: Just as run the command 'exit'

Answer (score 3):

The shell exits when it reaches EOF on its standard input (that's why you type <kbd>Control-D</kbd> to logout).  When it has finished reading from `file`, it will exit as there is no more input to come.

Comment: e...I just redirection the stdin and have not read anyting from the input, How can it finished reading from the file?

Comment: After the redirection, the shell isn't reading from the terminal anymore; it's reading from the file. It doesn't start reading from the terminal again after it finishes reading the file: it exits.

Comment: As @chepner sadi, after the redirection, the script continues executing; any further input from standard input comes from the file instead of the terminal.  When there is no more input from the file, it will terminate.  Exactly how and when depends on the commands executed and what they read, but when there's no more input available, the shell will end up exiting.

Answer (score 0):

from bash's BASH_BUILTINS man page (`man exec`)

```
   exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
          If command is specified, it replaces the shell.  No new  process
          is  created.  The arguments become the arguments to command.  If
          the -l option is supplied, the shell places a dash at the begin-
          ning  of  the  zeroth  argument passed to command.  This is what
          login(1) does.  The -c option causes command to be executed with
          an  empty environment.  If -a is supplied, the shell passes name
          as the zeroth argument to the executed command.  If command can-
          not  be executed for some reason, a non-interactive shell exits,
          unless the shell option execfail is enabled, in  which  case  it
          returns  failure.   An  interactive shell returns failure if the
          file cannot be executed.  If command is not specified, any redi-
          rections take effect in the current shell, and the return status
          is 0.  If there is a redirection error, the return status is  1.
```

So, as you can see, if a command finishes -> exit, and if a command fails -> exit...
Redirecting a file into exec will fail...
Unless it contains a line that is a valid code that **also** doesn't exit till you quit it.
(otherwise it will run, and exit...)